# Has an official release date of A Memory of Light been published?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

Has an official release date of *A Memory of Light* been published yet?

I have seen some guesses by some book stores of November 2012, but has Brandon Sanderson or anyone related to Team Jordan made a statement?

Comment: Closing per http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-do-we-deal-with-questions-about-rumors-and-release-dates

Comment: Voting to reopen. It's not a very good question (and wasn't at the time, either) but release date questions are now on-topic. For what it's worth, wikipedia says that it was released on January 8, 2013

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Brandon's latest post about this said it will not be out before Summer 2012, and should definitely be out by November.  You can keep an eye on his progress [here](http://www.brandonsanderson.com/), and he also posts about it on Twitter under [@BrandSanderson](https://twitter.com/#!/BrandSanderson).

Comment: Bless @BrandonSanderson - he tweets regularly about AMOL. Also, check the AMOL section on tor.com : http://www.tor.com/features/series/a-memory-of-light

Answer (score 1):

The [WoT Wiki](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/A_Memory_of_Light) says that publication was pushed back from late 2011 to March 2012. However, Sanderson [tweeted](https://twitter.com/#!/BrandSanderson/status/112648292525023232) that March is unlikely and it could be as late as November.

Answer (score 0):

Originally expected to have been published around March 2012, the book was delayed several times, and the hardcover edition was eventually released on January 8, 2013.

[ISBN   978-0-7653-2595-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Memory_of_Light)